# draw circles using border radius

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to convert some divs, using border radius.
I almost obtain it, but sometimes divs look like 'eggs' haha
This is my css:

```
#div{   /*div central*/
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -20%;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    background: #00A8D9;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:3px solid #000;
}
#divSupIzq,#divSupDer,#divInfIzq,#divInfDer{    /*DIVs: left-top , right-top, left-bottom, right-bottom*/
    background: #ddd;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border:3px solid #fff;
    position:absolute;
}
#divSupIzq{  /*Div left-top*/
    top:15%;
    left:10%;
}
#divSupDer{ /*Div right-top*/
    top:15%;
    right:10%;
}
#divInfIzq{ /*Div left-bottom*/
    bottom:15%;
    left:10%;
}
#divInfDer{ /*Div right-bottom*/
    bottom:15%;
    right:10%;
}
```

And in html, I use javascript / jQuery in order to change the content of each div (basically text in divs: left-top,right-top, left-bottom, right-bottom ; and number in central div) on depending of the size of each div:

```
$('#div').resize(function(height){
                    var fuente = $(this).height()/2;
                    var margen = (fuente / 2)-5;
                    $('.contenido').css('font-size',fuente+'px');
                    $('.contenido').css('margin-top',margen+'px');  
                });
```

This is how I see in Ripple extension of chrome:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k71kz5lahfolw95/screen.JPG

**Can you help me in order to divs are always circles, and not eggs?** 
Thanks in advance, Daniel

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? And since you are using percentages everywhere, the shapes will probably change depending on the window size.

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eC3jq/) from the above information.

Comment: Yeah, I need use percents in order to adapt to different resolutions

Comment: You need an outside container that is square.

Comment: But how? I don't know how make it.

Comment: Firstly, I tried it using media queries...but it was quite hard for control each resolution...and now I'm trying with percents...What do you advise me?

Comment: Try it like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/VJWDu/1/)

Comment: Added like your fiddle, but it continues equal...

Answer (score 9):

To draw a circle:

**HTML**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GF7wz/) is the fiddle of the above.

Fixed width and height: http://jsfiddle.net/eC3jq/1/

`circle` contained in a `div` so that % width and height work properly: http://jsfiddle.net/eC3jq/2/

Source: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Yes, but I need with percents. Thanks friend.

Comment: You can't do it with percent unless you put it in a div, because height and width of browser window are different. So, their % will also be different.

Comment: So, how can I draw circles and positionate them well in different resolutions of screen? What do you advise me? Thanks for help

Comment: Just use `margin: 0 auto;` to position it in the middle. See the edit

Comment: @DanielGarcia,  I guess you are looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eC3jq/2/)

Comment: I need this interface, adaptable to different resolutions ... but I dont' sure what is the most way..  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji1j4vmwm1fjdfq/screen2.png

Comment: Do you think with media queries it's easier? i started using media queries, but it was being hard for me, and I'm trying with percents...

Comment: This is the fiddle of this app using media queries... But in some resolutions, circles overlay between them... :( http://jsfiddle.net/cN2pS/embedded/result/   Could you help me with it? Thanks for your help

Comment: If I use media queries, how can I emulate too much resolutions of screen, and create media queries on depending on these resolutions...Is there any tools for this? Regards

Comment: You can get the resolutions from JS and work on the styling at those resolutions using media queries. I'm currently not aware of any libraries/tools for media queries, sorry. :/

Comment: Bufff, I'm having nightmares with the interface, because my chiefs want the interface like that, and I'm delaying much time... I need be clear what is the best way

Comment: Media Queries are undoubtedly the way to go about stuff as they are there exactly for this kind of stuff. I hope you figure your way out. All the best mate. :)

Comment: Ok, tomorrow when I arrive to the office, I'll work hard using media queries, adapting these divs to different resolutions. When I have problems, I'll come here haha :) Regards

Answer (score 1):

## JQuery

This can be usefull too, if you copy all this code to you site, it will work. Or you can see a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/whLctrp4/

HTML code with calling JQuery function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="pies">
    </div>
```

Include JQuery

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

drawPie function - tak as parameters id/class html atribute, size (in px), percent of filling and color of the pie

```
    <script>

    function drawPie (id, size, percent, color) {                               
        var sizeString = "" + size + "px";                      
        var grad = 360/100*percent+90;      
        console.log(grad);
        var pie = $("<span></span>");

        pie.css({"width": sizeString, 
            "height": sizeString,               
            "display": "block",
            "border-radius": "50%",
            "background-color": color,                          
            "float": "left",
            "margin": "5px"             
        });         

        if(percent <= 50){
            pie.css({"background-image": "linear-gradient("+ grad + "deg, transparent 50%, white 50%), linear-gradient(90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)"});
        } else if (percent >= 100) {
            pie.css({"background-image": "none"});
        } else {                                
            pie.css({"background-image": "linear-gradient("+ (grad+180) + "deg, transparent 50%, "+color+" 50%), linear-gradient(+90deg, white 50%, transparent 50%)"});                
        }

        $(id).append(pie);
    }
```

For cycle for show, how it works:

```
    for(i=0; i<=100; i+=1){
        drawPie(".pies", 100, i, "orange");
    }

    </script>       

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add explanation on what makes you think your code works for OP.  This would be helpful for all viewers in future on why this is a solution

Answer (score 0):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XtTkG/3/

The demo works by making use of the resize event of the window object rather than the div itself. On each resize we size the div and its border radius, so that it renders as a perfect circle (i.e. width = height and radius = width/2)

Code:

```
$(window).resize(function(height) {
    var div = $('#div');
    var width = $('body').width() * 0.4;
    var radius = width/2;
    width += 'px';
    radius += 'px';
    div.css({
        width: width, height: width,
        '-moz-border-radius' : radius,
        '-webkit-border-radius' : radius,
        'border-radius' : radius
    });

    // rest of your code for font-size setting etc..
});

$(window).resize();
```

Comment: Wow! I'm going to test it! Thanks